# ggplot2: How to get symbols to stay the same for factors in two different scatterplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This problem has been driving me crazy. I am trying to make scatterplots with two different datasets. My dataframe is

```
structure(list(x1 = c(5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 8L, 4L), y1 = c(7L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), class1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
x2 = c(4L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), y2 = c(7L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), class2 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "A", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x1", 
"y1", "class1", "x2", "y2", "class2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

and looks like this:

```
x1  y1  class1  x2  y2  class2
5   7   A       4   7   B
3   5   B       8   5   A
4   6   A       7   1   A
5   4   A       5   4   A
4   1   B       6   5   B
8   5   B       2   8   A
5   6   B       5   4   A
6   9   B       4   5   B
3   8   B       5   8   B
4   4   A
5   5   A
6   6   A
8   7   A
4   8   A
```

I want to plot two scatterplots:

1. `x1` vs `y1`
2. `x2` vs `y2`

In each scatterplot, I want the symbol shape to be determined by the classes `class1` and `class2`. Since the classes are either `A` or `B`, I want the symbol shape to stay the same in both plots.

I am using the following code to try and do this:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw()) # omit grey background

qplot(x1, y1, data=df, shape=I(21), fill=I("gray"), size = I(4),alpha = I(0))+
  stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black", size=1) + geom_point(shape=factor(class1),        size=I(4))

qplot(x2, y2, data=df, shape=I(21), fill=I("gray"), size = I(4),alpha = I(0))+
  stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black", size=1) + geom_point(shape=factor(class2),     size=I(4))
```

It works fine if the length of my `x1/y1` and `x2/y2` are the same - in that case the symbols stay the same in both plots.  However, if the length of the datasets are different (like in the dataframe example above), then a third symbol is introduced into the second plot.

Does anyone know how I can get the same symbols for `A` and `B` in both plots?

EDIT:  If I try the method suggested below by Didzis Elferts

```
ggplot(df,aes(x1,y1,shape=class1))+geom_point(size=4)+
scale_shape_manual(breaks=c("A","B"),values=c(15,16))

ggplot(df,aes(x2,y2,shape=class2))+geom_point(size=4)+
scale_shape_manual(breaks=c("A","B"),values=c(15,16))
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 2 provided.
```

EDIT 2:  Didzis Elferts recommended the following solution

```
df$class2<-factor(df$class2,levels=c("A","B"))
```

However, when I try to add a regression line to each scatterplot using

```
ggplot(df,aes(x1,y1,shape=class1))+geom_point(size=4)+ scale_shape_manual(breaks=c("A","B"),values=c(15,16))+ stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black", size=1)

qplot(x2, y2, data=df, shape=class1)+ stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black", size=1) + geom_point(size=4)+ scale_shape_manual(breaks=c("A","B"),values=c(15,16))
```

ggplot2 adds a separate regression line for each class.  Instead, I need just a single regression line based on the data from both classes together (even though they have different symbols).

Comment: Sorry about the table formatting, I can't ever figure out how to do that properly.  =(

Comment: Thanks for fixing my table Dave Chen!

Comment: To better show your data in question you could add result of dput(df)

Comment: Thanks Didzis, I will edit my original post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that in your data for `class2` empty cell is one of the factor levels.

```
str(df$class2)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "","A","B": 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 3 1 ...
```

You can change this empty cell to `NA` by setting new factor levels.

```
df$class2<-factor(df$class2,levels=c("A","B"))
```

One way to ensure that both plots have the same legend and symbols is to use `scale_shape_manual()` and then set `breaks=` and `values=` (shape symbols) you need.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x1,y1,shape=class1))+geom_point(size=4)+
    scale_shape_manual(breaks=c("A","B"),values=c(15,16))

ggplot(df,aes(x2,y2,shape=class2))+geom_point(size=4)+
    scale_shape_manual(breaks=c("A","B"),values=c(15,16))
```

### Update - one regression line

To get only one regression line `shape=` should be placed directly inside `aes()` of `geom_point()`.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x2,y2))+geom_point(size=4,aes(shape=class2))+
           scale_shape_manual(breaks=c("A","B"),values=c(15,16))+
           stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black", size=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Didzis Elferts!  However, when I try running that code with my example above, I get the following error for the second plot: "Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 2 provided."  I believe that ggplot2 is somehow thinking that the second plot has a third class, which is why it's assigning a different symbol (?).

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH Didzis Elferts!  Your solution worked wonderfully, and I was able to use it in both my example above and in my "real" dataset!  Thanks again, I would've had to make my plots in some other software without your solution!

Comment: Dear Didizis, I spoke too soon.  While your solution does give the same symbols, when I try to add the regression line, ggplot2 makes a separate line for each class in each plot.  I acutally was able to get the same symbols earlier, but I need to have just a single regression plot which is why I had added the "stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black", size=1)" in my code.  When I do this with your solution, it gives 2 regression lines.  Do you know how to get just a single regression line?  I will add this to my original post.

Comment: For example, I get two regression lines in the second plot using qplot(x2, y2, data=df, shape=class1)+ stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black", size=1) + geom_point(size=4)+ scale_shape_manual(breaks=c("A","B"),values=c(15,16))

Comment: To get just one regression line remove shape=class1 from qplot() call and use geom_point(aes(shape=class1),size=4)

Comment: Thank you Didzis!  SimonO101 is right!  I'm sorry, I'm not very good at R as you can see.  Many thanks to you, I really appreciate it!